# How to manage Spotify access token in express app

Tags: node.js, express, spotify

I'm writing an Express + Typescript application that, among other things, has an API endpoint which allows the user to search for a track. The endpoint receives a track name as a URL parameter, requests an access token from Spotify, uses the access token to query the Spotify Web API for matching tracks, then returns the data in JSON format. My problem is that I'm using the [spotify-web-api-node](https://github.com/thelinmichael/spotify-web-api-node) library to interact with the API and so far I've only been able to make it work by requesting a new access token each time the route is accessed. I've tried adding middleware to request the access token elsewhere so it doesn't need to be done in this specific route, but it seemingly executes the route before the middleware, thus executing the API call without first getting the access token. Here is my working solution so far

```
import { Router, Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';
import SpotifyWebApi from 'spotify-web-api-node';

const spotifyRouter = Router();

const spotifyApi: SpotifyWebApi = new SpotifyWebApi({
    clientId: /* My client ID */,
    clientSecret: /* My client secret */
})

spotifyRouter.get('/search/track/:trackName', (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    spotifyApi.clientCredentialsGrant()
    .then(data => spotifyApi.setAccessToken(data.body['access_token']))
    .then(() => { return spotifyApi.searchTracks(req.params.trackName) })
    .then(data => res.json(data.body))
    .catch(error => res.json(error));

})

export default spotifyRouter;
```

So to reiterate, I'm wondering how I can improve the management of the access token so it doesn't have to get a new one each time the above route is used.

Thanks.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that this is using Spotify's [Client Credentials Flow](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/#client-credentials-flow)

Comment: Is the "access_token" a refresh token? Does it break any best practices by getting a new one each time? I only ask, because this will determine how to best answer this question.

Comment: The access token can be used for an hour before a new one must be requested, and according to the Spotify API reference there is no way to refresh the use of this token. This leads me to believe my code should use the token for as long as it's valid before requesting a new one, although Spotify's documentation makes no mention of how it should be used.

Comment: Ok that's actually good news, you will be able to generate a new token for each request. This is what you could call a refresh token (although not identical). If there are no rate limits on token generation, you are safe to continue as you are.

Comment: Great. I'm still concerned about what I would do if I wanted to add calls to different Spotify endpoints without too much code reuse, but thanks for your help.

Comment: If the code is reusable between different endpoints, you can create middleware to generate this code and pass it to your routes.